# Name comparison algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

### To check if a name is inside an anti-terrorism list.

In addition of the given name, also search for similar names (possible aliases).

*Example:*
given name => Bin Laden **alert!**
given name => Ben Larden  *mhm.. suspicious name, matchs at xx% with Bin Laden*

How can I do this?

- using PHP
- names are 100% correct, since they are from official sources
- i'm Italian, but i think this won't be a problem, since names are international
- names can be composed of several words: `Najmiddin Kamolitdinovich JALOLOV`
- looking for companies and people

I looked at differents algorithms: do you think that Levenshtein can do the job?
thank you in advance!

ps i got some problems to format this text, sorry :-)

Comment: Have you tried Levenshtein? Are you using a database?

Comment: This question scares me in all sorts of ways!

Comment: I bet that's the latest in airport security. Check the passenger lists for suspicious names. And when those book a flight, they have to store their liquids not in one, but two plastic bags :D

Comment: Mainly I feel sorry for poor old Ben Larden

Comment: @Paul yeah! Poor fellow. Got teased in school, and now this. Add to it that he likes to [pay in cash and lives next to a bus route](http://news.nationalpost.com/2010/08/11/pay-with-cash-your-neighbour-could-be-a-terrorist-banned-u-k-ad-suggests/)...!

Comment: @Gordon the good thing is that you only need an Umlaut in your name to get through okay. You see, the search form is ISO-8859-1 encoded, while the data base is UTF-8.

Comment: I so hope this is homework...

Comment: If you end up coding these stupid security measures that even a 4 year-old can bypass, the terrorists have already won.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say your best bet to get this working with PHP's native functions are

- [`soundex()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) — Calculate the soundex key of a string
- [`levenshtein()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) - Calculate Levenshtein distance between two strings
- [`metaphone()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php) - Calculate the metaphone key of a string
- [`similar_text()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) - Calculate the similarity between two strings

Since you are likely matching the names against a database (?), you might also want to check whether your database provides any Name Matching Functions.

Google also provided a PDF with a nice overview on Name Matching Algorithms:

- http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/brian.randell/Genealogy/NameMatching.pdf

Comment: mhm... ok but how can i handle this? Gabino Leon BLANCO BAHOQUE vs Gabino BAHOQUE?

Comment: @tampe you have to split names into separate parts. I'd probably give surnames precendence over first and middle names.

Answer (score 2):

The Levenshtein function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) can do this:

```
$string1 = 'Bin Laden';
$string2 = 'Ben Larden';
levenshtein($string1, $string2); // result: 2
```

Set a threshold on this result and determine if the name looks similar.